# "Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie"

Tags: asp.net, security, web-applications

In my web application, only the login page has SSL enabled. In a security scan result, I received the following error, `"Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie"`. My question is how to do add secure attribute only for the login.aspx page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't—if you did then once the user left the SSL login page their cookie would disappear and they would cease to be logged in. If you *must* have a hybrid partially-SSL site then you will have to put up with the warning.

The real security issue is that you have a partially-SSL site; the cookie warning is just a symptom of that. It is usually best to serve everything over SSL.